# Were there no gifted people other than Richard when Drefan was around?

Tags: the-sword-of-truth

Having been reading "Pillars of Creation", it now makes a bit more sense about Drefan. But, it got me wondering: Was there no one else that was gifted in Aydindril while Drefan was around? Wouldn't even Richard's gift have been giving him this nagging feeling that Drefan "wasn't there"? Given that Richard's gift works on instinct, I'd figure that his gift should have given him this inkling that something just wasn't right with Drefan.

Comment: But was he really one of those "holes" in the world? If I recall correctly, not **every** ungifted Rahl was so.

Comment: @MatteoTassinari According to the Pillars of Creation book, EVERY ungifted Rahl is a hole in the world.

Comment: I must have misread it then O.o or maybe an error in translation? I do not have the original text after all.

Comment: I believe that it was explained when Jensen was talking to Althea, and explaining it all to her.

Answer (score 2):

Just finished ready Pillars of Creation. They don't explicitly say it, but I got the impression that not every Rahl child is either the gifted heir or pristinely ungifted. It sounds like you get a few "normals" scattered in there.

Although, this does raise the questions about the voices Drefan heard. We know that Jennsen and Oba heard and listened to voices, which were identified as being the Keeper influencing him. It is stated that Drefan heard voices, which makes me think that he was probably also pristinelu ungifted.

In terms of Richard being able to detect Drefan, I don't think that this is possible for him. He spends the whole of Naked Empire with pristinely ungifted people and there is no indication that he can detect them for what they are. In fact, everyone is equally surprised when Cara touches Owen and they figure it all out.

So, the way I read it is that although Drefan was likely pristinely ungifted, Richard has no way of detecting him. As far as I remember, there are no other gifted people in Aydindril during Temple of the Winds, so nobody would be able to detect him anyways.

Answer (score 0):

In Temple of the Winds it states how Drefan found his way to Richard through the bond to the Lord Rahl. If he was pristine, then the magic of the bond wouldn't have worked on him.  I also believe that one of the character's in the book "saw" the rage of the Sword of Truth in Drefan's eyes, again showing how magic was able to affect him.  I would have to agree that Drefan all in all seems like a "normie" to me and not a "pristine"

Comment: I've read this over a few times and I'm not quite sure what you're answer to if there were any other gifted people around is. Could you [edit] it to expand on that point? (Though I suppose this is a partial answer as it does address the second question about Drefan).+

Answer (score 0):

In the Temple of the Winds, the spirits bind Kahlen's power so she can't use it on Drefan during their marriage. If he was pristinely Ungifted, her power wouldn't be able to work on him, and the spirits would have known that. Moreover, Darken Rahl would have known that, since he's the one who orchestrated the marriage from the underworld.
So it's safe to say, no, Drefan wasn't Pristine.
And I'm sure we could theorycraft reasons as to why. But the likely answer is, Goodkind didn't come up with them yet.

Comment: I may be missing something here, but this doesn't appear to answer the main question asked -- _"Were there no gifted people other than Richard when Drefan was around?"_ -- and feels more like a response to [CombatWombat's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/151870/122024). Please note that the 'Your Answer' field should only be used to answer the question, not to comment on or previous answers. There's a [dedicated feature for posting comments](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment), but full access to that is a privilege reserved for those with 50 or more reputation.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFF stack exchange! While you're here please take the [tour] and checkout the [help] Answers should stand on their own, so please do edit in more information if you're assuming something mentioned elsewhere.